# Use Domain Classes from a Plugin

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails3

i'm currently trying out the first time grails 3.

I created an plugin (which should contain some Domain Classes) and an simple application.

Now I'm getting following Error:

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Either class [de.foo.Author] is not a domain class or GORM has not been initialized correctly or has already been shutdown. Ensure GORM is loaded and configured correctly before calling any methods on a GORM entity.`

Author Domain Class:

```
class Author { 
  String name 
}
```

I'm unsing Grails 3.2.9 with following dependencies:

**Plugin**

```
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
compile "org.grails:grails-core"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
compile "org.grails:grails-dependencies"
compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"
compile "org.grails.plugins:cache"
compile "org.grails.plugins:scaffolding"
console "org.grails:grails-console"
profile "org.grails.profiles:web-plugin"
provided "org.grails:grails-plugin-services"
provided "org.grails:grails-plugin-domain-class"
testCompile "org.grails:grails-plugin-testing"
testCompile "org.grails.plugins:geb"
testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:2.47.1"
testRuntime "net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.18"

compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5"
compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.1.3.Final"
compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:5.1.3.Final"

compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-cas:3.0.0'
compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.1.2'

compile "org.apache.poi:poi:3.16"
compile "org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.16"
compile "org.apache.poi:ooxml-schemas:1.0"

compile 'org.grails.plugins:wkhtmltopdf:1.0.0.RC7'
```

**Application**

```
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
compile "org.grails:grails-core"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
compile "org.grails:grails-dependencies"
compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"
compile "org.grails.plugins:cache"
compile "org.grails.plugins:scaffolding"
compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5"
compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.1.3.Final"
compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:5.1.3.Final"
console "org.grails:grails-console"
profile "org.grails.profiles:web"
runtime "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-grails:2.14.1"
testCompile "org.grails:grails-plugin-testing"
testCompile "org.grails.plugins:geb"
testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:2.47.1"
testRuntime "net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.18"
runtime "com.h2database:h2"

compile "de.foo:bar:0.1"

runtime 'com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-grails:2.14.3'
assets 'com.bertramlabs.plugins:less-asset-pipeline:2.14.3'

runtime "mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.29"
```

Do you guys have any suggestion or answers for me how I store domain classes in the plugin and use it in some applications?

Comment: When are you getting that error?  And just to be 100% sure: same version of grails in the plugin and in the application?

Comment: yes same version in the plugin and in the application. I'm getting this error while running the app.

Comment: well the grails version was the same but the GORM version was not the same. setting both to the same version resolved the problem

Answer (score -1):

For GORM errors, the versions do have to be the same.  For other grails stuff, the groovy versions typically have to be the same for binary compatibility.  While it's not 100% required to keep every version the same in every case, it's a lot more necessary in grails 3 than it was in grails 2, and is probably just a best practice at this point.

Comment: "While it's not 100% required to keep every version the same in every case, it's a lot more necessary in grails 3 than it was in grails 2" - That isn't really the case.  Grails 3 makes it easy (intentionally) for you to mix and match different versions of thing.  In fact, in recent Grails 3 releases we have pulled the GORM version out into a properties file specifically so you can upgrade that dependency independent of the rest of the app.

Comment: Bad wording on my part, then.  It's necessary (or best) for all plugins as well as your application to have the same version of gorm.  Or the same version of groovy, or grails.  In grails 2, it wasn't a big deal (usually) to have a plugin on 2.3.9 and the application on 2.5.1, for example.  Now...it's a big deal.

Comment: It is fortunately a lot EASIER now to pick a different version though, I agree.  It's a bit of a pain if you're using a third party plugin that hasn't picked that version, but that's a discussion for another forum.  :-)